# How to play next video in MPMoviePlayer?

Tags: iphone

I have implement an application.In which there is list of videos.when user touch on the video then video play in MPMoviePlayer.But when video is finished then i want to play another video automatically.Is it possible?

Comment: Could you please post your code for playing two videos one after the another.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Do you want it to play another one randomly?  You could do that.  Or do you have an NSArray that contains all the different MPMoviePlayer URLs to play in order?  If you do, then loop through the array objects and play each.  You will have to have a `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` to know when each videos finish so you can start the next one.